# Replace DLL refs with Project refs for project dependencies in Visual Studio C# solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to programmatically replace DLL refs with Project refs for project dependencies in Visual Studio C#/VB.NET solution?

**BACKGROUND:**

I'm working with some legacy code where dependencies for each project are mostly referenced as compiled DLLs instead of including project reference from corresponding project in solution or even worse - referenced straight from GAC!

Right now I have to manually remove each DLL reference and replace it with project reference from VS UI for each solution out of dozens projects.

Editing the project/solution XML .csproj/.sln files is not straightforward due to GUIDs:

```
<!--typical DLL reference-->

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyDLL, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b6d1e0267e1acba, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>...\MyDLL.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<!--typical Project reference-->

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyDLL\MyDLL.csproj">
      <Project>{3cc27830-3d6b-4071-85e5-5a4006f11142}</Project>
      <Name>MyDLL</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You could change a couple of references and compare how they were listed in .csproj file before and after the change. If there is a pattern, which   would let you generalize, you could replace them by using regex in a custom console app or some text editor.

Comment: @Edin how about project hashes?

Comment: I guess you mean project GUIDs - you can resolve them from single  project files by finding element ProjectGuid. This is possible to code, however it depends how many projects you need to replace and if the time to do that would be much less than programming an automated solution... or if you need to do it over and over again for some reason. And let's not forget, coding automated solution is more fun :)

Comment: "project are mostly referenced as compiled DLLs instead of including project reference" I wouldn't be going crazy about it. In a large app I would use DLL references-not project references. Proj refs good for small, single solution applications. Create a bin folder level of solution(s), and reference from bin, and build into bin. For the GAC part-you're correct. Don't reg your stuff in GAC, especially for development and testing. Imagine, you create distribution package and it works on test server. But on deployment - not.because you didn't pack a DLL and it lives on test server in GAC already

Comment: @T.S. dll refs do not allow "go to definition" or "find usage", dll refs can get out of date, finally dll refs are hard to maintain in source control. I only see 3 situations for using dll refs - too large code-base for one solution, source code not available or/and third-party dependency.

Comment: I soundly disagree with you. Designing your dev environment is just as important as designing objects in your assemblies. DLL refs don't go out of date because you should use continuous integration or periodic builds. You don't ever store your DLLs in source control. Store only 3rd party. Your build process should load DLLS into network drive and then you can have .bat file to get latest. You can always rebuild a project or 2. "go to definition" or "find usage" - this is a small issue if you designed your "cake" well. If for some reason, you need to search entire code base for usage of some...

Comment: You can always have another solution to which you can add all of your projects. But you would rarely use it. Because you usually will have a point of interest solution, lets say BLL, vs Common. But if you have 5 projects - go ahead and set proj references. Ad a build master I do it on our packaged products. We build 3-5 projects that wrap rest of the 250-project system.

Comment: 250 projects is not our scale, we operate with only few dozen projects, hence optimizing build time is not essential. Our CI is very similar to what you described. Anyway find usage and definitions is big deal due to tight integration between projects. Yep, ref dlls next to source code is very bad legacy design.

Comment: 250 projects?? Then only building a visual studio add-in might help you ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this plug-in .. It might help on your problem

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/056617a4-da39-4d7b-8ecf-933009d9b721

It has description below

> Switches references from file to projects (and vice versa) references
>   when adding projects. References are reverted when the project is
>   removed.
>
> usage:
>
> You are developing project A which has a file reference to assembly
>   "b.dll". At some point you need to make changes to "b.dll" . So you
>   add project "B" to the solution. The ReferenceSwitcher will detect
>   that project B produces an assembly called "b.dll" and ask if you want
>   to switch all references from "b.dll" to project B.
>
> Then at some point later, you no longer need project B in your
>   solution, so you remove project B. The reference switcher will
>   detected that references to B used to point to "b.dll" and ask you if
>   you would like to update them.
>
> More info here:
>   http://markkemper1.blogspot.com/2011/09/project-to-file-reference-switcher-for.html

**Edit:**
there are lots of plug-in available to solve your purpose check them out

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/197d94f6-6276-471d-853d-a5a322ccb08c

OR search them all

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=reference&pageIndex=2

Comment: this is great! let me check out if any of them work in my case. The only problem is that these 2 plugins may not be compatible with VS 2015.

Comment: i hope they will .. try to use first https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/197d94f6-6276-471d-853d-a5a322ccb08c .. i think ..it is solely made to help you :)